# How to set onChanged value of Switch

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

I have a switch which toggle the app theme but there is some errors on the code

```
Switch(value: AppStyleMode.isSwitched, onChanged: (value)=> AppStyleMode.switchMode())
```

My Theme file

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class AppStyleMode extends ChangeNotifier {
      bool isSwitched = true; 
      Color primaryBG = Colors.white;
      Color appBarBG = Colors.yellow;
      
    
      switchMode() {
        if (isSwitched == true) {
          primaryBG = Colors.black];
          appBarBG = Colors.grey[400];
         
          isSwitched = false;
        } else {
          //if it is dark mode currently switch to light
          primaryBG = Colors.white;
          appBarBG = Colors.yellow;
      
          isSwitched = true;
        }
    
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

Errors on Switch :

[image: Switch Error]

Comment: Are you using any particular state management package like provider ?

Comment: i am not using a provider, is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any particular state management packages,

First, you would have to create an instance of your `AppStyleMode` class, so that you can use values from it and also listen to it's changes.

Assuming you have a `StatefulWidget`,

first define your `AppStyleMode` in it's `State`,

```
class MyState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  late AppStyleMode appStyleMode;
```

Then in your `initState`, initialise it and add a listener to it.

```
void initState () {
  super.initState();
  
  appStyleMode = AppStyleMode();

  // Also add a listener to it and call setState to rebuild your StatefulWidget
  appStleMode.addListener(() => {
    setState(() {});
  });
}
```

Then you can use it in your `build` by using your variable `appStyleMode` like this,

```
Switch(value: appStyleMode.isSwitched, onChanged: (value) => appStyleMode.switchMode())
```

I would rather suggest you look into a State management solution like [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or [Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get). But it is not compulsory.